# Next and previous array index

Tags: arrays, indexing, yii2

I have this array

```
$ages = array("Peter"=>22, "Clark"=>32, "John"=>28);
```

In my view , currently i am displaying the details about clark . how can i display the next and previous member details in Next and Prev button click. (Using array index). I am using yii2 .

Answer (score 0):

You could use  the PHP next() and prev()  functions

```
  $my_elem = next($ages);

  $my_elem = prev($ages);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php